# JBoss logging subsystem configuration define lower level logger for a specific package

Tags: jboss, jboss-logging

Is it possible in JBoss logging subsystem configuration to set root log level to "INFO" and to define lower level such as "DEBUG" for a specific package ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible. For clarity loggers are defined by names and not packages. That said, the typical logger names are class/package names. If you have a class named `org.wildfly.example.SimpleResource` and you get the logger like `Logger.getLogger(SimpleResource.class)` your logger name is `org.wildfly.example.SimpleResource`.

By default the root logger is set to INFO. If you want to add debug logging for your logger, you can do that in CLI or the HAL web console. A CLI example would look like:

```
/subsystem=logging/logger=org.wildfly.example.SimpleResource:add(level=DEBUG)
```

If you want to see debug messages on the console you likely need to do something like this too:

```
/subsystem=logging/console-handler=CONSOLE:write-attribute(name=level, value=DEBUG)
```

You can also be more generic with the logger name to add debugging for all loggers within the name segments.

```
/subsystem=logging/logger=org.wildfly.example:add(level=DEBUG)
```